# Graph-based searching vs Stochastic Based Searching

Tags: java, graph, path-finding, a-star, stochastic

So far, I have only known A* search and some of its variants on a grid. Recently, I have heard of Stochastic Search algorithms such as Rapidly Random Exploring Trees (RRT) and how they are very good when the search problem becomes very big, but delivers terribly suboptimal paths. Sadly, I have not found any comparisons that benchmark RRT or other variants with A* and its variants. Does anyone know or have links that details the performance difference of the two algorithms on a very large grid (2048x2048 or higher)? Non-grid search problems are fine too

What I have found so far: http://movingai.com/GPPC/ that shows Tree Cache, based on RRT, to be extremely faster than all of the A* variants

If not a benchmark, are there any available implementations of an RRT in Java? EDIT: Should Have googled before I asked. http://correll.cs.colorado.edu/?p=1623